In Rust, how can I unittest a struct in isolation from any structs it depends on?
I'm still fairly new to Rust and coming from almost exclusively Python development. I've been trying to find a solution to this problem for a while now, but I'm also considering that I am approaching the problem in a way that's trying to be too pythonic to work in Rust.
Say I have a struct "Person" as defined in one file:
// src/person.rs

pub struct Person {
    pub age: i16,
}

impl Person {
    pub fn get_older(&mut self, by_how_much: i16) {
        self.age += by_how_much;
    }
}

And in another file I have the struct Company:
// src/company.rs

use crate::person::Person;

pub struct Company {
    pub ceo: Person
}

impl Company {
    pub fn celebrate_ceos_birthday(&mut self) {
        self.ceo.get_older(1);
    }
}

In the Company file, I would now like to write a unit-test to tests the behavior of the celebrate_ceos_birthday function:
// src/company.rs

#[test]
fn test_celebrate_ceos_birthday() {
    let test_ceo = Person { age: 44 };
    let mut test_company = Company { ceo: test_ceo };

    test_company.celebrate_ceos_birthday();

    assert_eq!(test_company.ceo.age, 45)
}

The problem that I have with this is that the test is now also dependent on the Person struct. To me, that goes against the idea of a unit-test. In Python, I could easily define a new "MockPerson" object inside the test (module) which simulates the interface of the real object as the Company object is using it. Of course, due to the strict guidelines, if I try that in Rust, the compiler will tell me that its expecting a "Person" struct and not a "MockPerson".
I have also tried around with using dynamic traits, but could not get it to work due to unknown size at compile time errors. I also looked into the mockall framework but havent found a way to use it for exactly what I want. Is there a recommended way to unit-test nested structs like this in Rust or do I need to abandon my ideas of how unit-tests should look?

As someone who strictly follows TDD in languages like C# and JavaScript, I have to admit that in Rust you can't really unit test in the same way. I've found myself relying more and more heavily on Rust's compiler and type system to ensure that my code is working properly, writing integration tests as a sanity check. It felt wrong at first, but I've experienced no increase in rigid code or fragile logic as time goes on. If you're interested, check out the typestate pattern and this video on compiler-driven development: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kdpfhj3VM04

If you use dyn you need to use Box.

This is easy to do by wrapping the behaviour expected of Person in a trait, then making your Company struct generic over that trait (don't use dyn here):
pub trait CanGetOlder {
   fn get_older (&mut self, by_how_much: i16);
}

pub struct Company<T> {
    pub ceo: T
}

impl<T: CanGetOlder> Company<T> {
    pub fn celebrate_ceos_birthday (&mut self) {
        self.ceo.get_older (1);
    }
}

Then in person.rs:
pub struct Person {
    pub age: i16,
}

impl CanGetOlder for Person {
    pub fn get_older (&mut self, by_how_much: i16) {
        self.age += by_how_much;
    }
}

And in your test, you can implement CanGetOlder for your MockPerson and test a Company<MockPerson>

Why not dyn? Depending on performance concerns, it may be better.

@ChayimFriedman dyn is meant for the case where you want to switch implementations dynamically at runtime (e.g. depending on a configuration parameter). If the crate itself has reason to use dyn independently of the tests, then by all means the tests might as well use it too. But it doesn't seem to be the case here, and since dyn comes with a performance cost it's better not to pay that cost just so that tests may use a different implementation from the main crate (especially since the tests don't have any reason to change implementations dynamically either).

Generics also have costs, in compile time and in syntax. dyn is not meant to be used somewhere other than where it's advantages outweigh its disadvantages.
